# Spring WS and CXF Binding

Tags: jaxb, cxf, spring-ws

I want to implement a webservice client using Spring WS JAXB and CXF.
I use CXF to generate my Stubs from a  WSDL file.
This WSDL contains the following schema :

         
         
         
         
         
         
      
For this schema the only thing that cxf generates is an ObjectFactory and no stub.
I want to use Spring Ws marshalSendAndReceive method to send a request to my service but I don't know how to construct my request object from what was generated with CXF.

Someone can help ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need CXF to generate the JAXB types from the WSDL file, JDK comes with a tool called xjc which can do this for you  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html

Can you try using this and see if the artifacts created with this tool suffice.